# Не могу забиндить в progressbar свойство value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Есть Progress Bar

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Height="50" Value="{Binding MyVar,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
```

Есть свойство с которым я свойство Value хочу связать `public int MyVar { get; set; }` При изменении свойства MyVar ничего не происходит,хотя по идее Value должен вместе с MyVar меняться,хотя я много где читал ,что должно работать.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема, судя по всему, здесь:

```
public int MyVar { get; set; }
```

Вы должны реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Как-то так:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int myVar = 0;
    public int MyVar
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { if (myVar != value) { myVar = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает,но разве без реализации данного интерфейса не должно работать?

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos: Смотрите. Binding должен же как-то узнать, что значение поменялось? Он же не может просто постоянно перечитывать. Есть два пути: реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged` и наследование от `DependencyObject` + кодировать свойство как `DependencyProperty`. Оба работают, но для VM обычно принятно использовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.